# I am running the following script in Google apps script - response sending cc and bcc

Tags: javascript, html

This code runs but cc set to multiple email id is it possible? `hodemail` is variable define. But only send a response to `test@test.com` and `hodemail` not sending?

```
var options = {} 

options.htmlBody = issue + '<br />' + "Done" + '<br />' +  remark; 
options.cc =  "test@test.com", hodemail;
MailApp.sendEmail(emailAddress , subject, issue, options);
```

Comment: `options.cc =  "test@test.com", hodemail;` does not do what you think - perhaps you need an array ... `options.cc =  ["test@test.com", hodemail];`

Comment: it should be error  -Invalid email: [L<?>;@4c886d34 (line 69, file "Code")

Comment: options.cc =  ["test@test.com", hodemail]; Error  - Invalid email: [L<?>;@4c886d34 (line 69, file "Code")

Comment: or perhaps `options.cc = ["test@test.com", hodemail].join(',');` then